# Appropriate image sizes to support various android phones & tablets

Tags: cocos2d-android

I am developing an android game in cocos2d. How many different sizes of images do I need to support android devices and tablets?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used that engine but if you mean by image size, device screen size, then you should use an scale.
I took for base the most bigger I could, 1280x800, the one that's on my tablet, just to be more precise in tablets too.
I apply the scale in (X,Y) to every image size and every operation that screen or screen size it's involved. i.e:
soldierBitmapX.move(movement*scaleX)
soldierBitmapY.move(movement*scaleY)

**scaleX** and **scaleY** represents your scale and **movement**  represent how many pixel your soodier will move.
This is an example to understand how to apply the scale. I don't recommend you to move your sprites with this operation but have in mind if you should apply the scale.
You can apply this to every screen possible and your game will feet exactly in all of it. Beware of for example QVGA screens, more "squared" in comparision with other standards and very small.

EDIT (how to get the scale):

```
_xMultiplier = (_screenWidth/(1280.0f/100.0f))/100.0f;
    _yMultiplier = (_screenHeight/(800.0f/100.0f))/100.0f;
    matrix.setScale(_xMultiplier, _yMultiplier);
```

this is an example of the scale applied to the matrix that we'll use.

Answer (score 0):

Through `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` Property you can easily scale the images .....as for example you take for tablet size is 1280 * 800 ,yo u can scale that sprite and use it; you can also use that image for smaller resolution e.g. 320 * 480.....